# Generate S3 pre-signed URL with v4 signature using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

The following does not work:

From the boto 3 docs:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls

This is my script with placeholder bucket and key values:

```
import boto3
import requests
from botocore.client import Config

# Get the service client.
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'mybucketname',
        'Key': 'myObject.txt'
    }
)

print url
response = requests.get(url)
print response
```

S3 responds with a 403:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>B5681E888657E2A1</RequestId>
<HostId>
FMS7oPPOXt4I0KXPPQwdBx2fyxze+ussMmy/BOWLVFusWMoU2zAErE08ez34O6VhSYRvIYFm7Bs=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide aws credentials with your boto3 client. [Docs here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#credentials)

If you need help getting access to your credentials on aws you can look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html).

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)

# Or via the Session
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```